# Как перевести время в moment в локальное?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Заказчики расположены по всей стране, при заказе время должно формироваться в заявке по часовому поясу Калининграда, что уже сделал. Когда заказ взят в работу, у исполнителя должно высвечиваться время по его часовому поясу, обратно в локальное время moment не переводит.

```
   var standart = moment().format('HH:mm');
   var now = moment(standart, 'HH:mm').tz("Europe/Kaliningrad").format("HH:mm");
   var deadline = moment(now, 'HH:mm').local().format('HH:mm');
```

Comment: Хранить даты в UTC или даже лучше unix timestamp! По другому только преобразовать локальную дату в timestamp, а потом преобразовать в нужный тебе часовой пояс..

Comment: не очень понял, как сделать